# Which android emulator is suitable for testing the load of third-party services?

Tags: android, testing, optimization, emulation, high-load

We came up with the idea to create software for testing services for android. We need to choose an android emulator.

I would like it to be:

- lightweight in RAM
- it was possible to change the SIM card
- there was an external software management functionality
- have the functionality of changing gps

in general, full phone emulation for minimal costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use every time andorid studio.

**PRO:**

- Easy to create Andorid phones
- Used by 100 milion users for testing their softwares
- lots of phone models

**CONS:**

- Require android studio  + sdk to work
- Require a good gpu (GT 1030/150 etc..)

You can find others emulator on https://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/

Comment: As I know, android studio is very good, but for our tasks it is redundant in terms of functionality.
But thank you for the link)

Comment: @AdmiraPaw No problem!